# Deserializing datetime objects with pickle on different Windows version

Tags: python, datetime, serialization, pickle

I have a dictionary that I would like to serialize and deserialize:

```
dict = {
    datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-10-01', '%Y-%m-%d'): {
        'product1': 3300.00,
    },
    datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-10-05', '%Y-%m-%d'): {
        'product1': 3000.00,
        'product2': 3000.50
    },
    datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-10-09', '%Y-%m-%d'): {
        'product1': 2700.00,
        'product2': 2800.50,
        'product3': 3600.00
    },
    datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-10-15', '%Y-%m-%d'): {
        'product1': 2500.00,
        'product2': 2700.00,
        'product4': 666.00
    }
}
```

I'm serializing and deserializing the dictionary using:

```
def get_current_datafile():
    with open(name='datafile.raw', mode='rb') as input_handle:
        input_dict = pickle.loads(input_handle.read())
    return input_dict

def write_datafile(new_dict):
    with open(name='datafile.raw', mode='wb') as output_handle:
        pickle.dump(new_dict, output_handle)
```

When I use the serialized file in one environment it works fine. But when I try to deserialize that same file on a different machine with Python environment set up in exactly same way it does not work, giving me a traceback claiming that I don't have datetime module installed, which is of course not true.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 92, in <module>
    Scraper().main()
  File "scraper.py", line 32, in main
    input_dict = self.get_current_datafile()
  File "scraper.py", line 82, in get_current_datafile
    input_dict = pickle.loads(input_handle.read())
  File "Python\lib\pickle.py", line 1388, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "Python\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "Python\lib\pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "Python\lib\pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named datetime
```

---

Only difference between environments I'm aware of is the Windows version - one machine is running:

- `Python 2.7.12`
- `Pickle r. 72223`
- `Windows 7 x64`

and the other one is running:

- `Python 2.7.12`
- `Pickle r. 72223`
- `Windows 10 x64`

---

The question is: **How should I configure my environments so I can consistently serialize and deserialize files between them?**

Comment: The temporary workaround that I used, was saving dates as plaintext strings and wrapping them in datetime after deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this exact problem. The issue was the line endings in the pickle file. Python 2.7.13 under windows saves them with a just a line feed.

On the second machine, I was retrieving them from GIT, and Tortoise GIT for windows was auto converting the line endings from just Line Feed to Carriage Return/Line Feed.

So, make sure that your line endings are not getting converted between machines. As soon as I converted back to only line feeds, the import error went away.